# ASP.NET Core 5 Web API no sign in authentication handler is registered for the Scheme 'cookies'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I am new to ASP.NET Identity, I have this log in function on my ASP.NET Core 5 Web API:

```
[HttpPost("login")]
public async Task<IActionResult> login([FromBody] LogIn logIn)
{
    var user = await _userManager.FindByEmailAsync(logIn.Email);
    if (user == null)
    {
        return NotFound("User Not Found!");
    }
    else if (user != null && await _userManager.CheckPasswordAsync(user, logIn.Password))
    {
        var claimsIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(new[]
            {
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, user.UserName),
                //...
            }, "Cookies");

        var claimsPrincipal = new ClaimsPrincipal(claimsIdentity);
        await Request.HttpContext.SignInAsync("Cookies", claimsPrincipal);
        return Ok();

    }
    else
    {
        return BadRequest("Email and/or Password not valid!");
    }
}
```

But when I sign in, I get this error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: No sign-in authentication handler
> is registered for the scheme 'Cookies'

How do I fix this? I will comment my `setup.cs` file because stack.

Answer (score 0):

make sure you [configure you services correctly](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/dotnet/net-development/using-auth-cookies-in-asp-net-core/), you need to add

---

In the `Startup` class, find the `ConfigureServices` method and type:

```
services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
  .AddCookie(options =>
  { // all your options
    options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
    // in dev
    options.Cookie.SecurePolicy = _environment.IsDevelopment()
      ? CookieSecurePolicy.None : CookieSecurePolicy.Always;
      options.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.Lax;
  });
```

---

for e.g. in the new 5.0

```
.AddCookie(config =>
        {
            config.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
            //options.Cookie.SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.Always;
            config.Cookie.SameSite = SameSite.Lax;
            config.Cookie.Name = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            config.LoginPath = "/Login"; // your login path
        });
```

Additional things

> 1. clear your cache
> 2. Enable HTTPS, find the option in VS
> 3. Turn off GDPR, which maybe now included in the template, and if the user does not accept it will not set the cookie.